# Are interfaces necessary for mocks in unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have read that you need to define interfaces in order to mock types but I am not sure how to interpret that.
For example, to mock FileSystem, instead of directly calling some I/O method, I can pass the object to the method and then mock it when calling from my test.
Why are unit test examples (like the one from SO question below), use interfaces?

```
void DoIt(IZipper zipper, IFileSystem fileSystem, IDllRunner runner)
{
   string path = zipper.Unzip(theZipFile);
   IFakeFile file = fileSystem.Open(path);
   runner.Run(file);
}
```

Could I not simply use arguments of respective types, and inject the object then?

E.g. in the GUICE guide, they advise to remove constructor work (e.g. no field inicialization with "new" keyword), but use parameters istead.

Comment: _and inject the object then_ - yes, but how to inject a mock for the object?  Try to write it down and see how far you get.

Comment: When calling the unit test, I would expect to simply create the object (concrete implementation) and pass it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I might see the issue - creating the actual instance means it will be "live", which means dependencies etc. With interface I will define my own behaviour, mocking responses I need.

Comment: Yes, you should test 1 'unit' at a time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman And also, it might not be possible (if the object reads DB connection, web service etc.). So I guess that is the reason why I create my own object with the same methods, but "deterministic" behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your mocking framework. Using Moq, you can mock concrete types as long as they aren't sealed and the members you want to mock are virtual. Interfaces are generally preferred because their members don't need to  (and can't) be marked as virtual. (There are other reasons to prefer interfaces such as to keep the coupling between your classes loose)

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

**Update**

Generally you will mock an instance of a type. Therefore you can't test static method calls like FileStream.Open because there is no instance to mock.

**Update**

Frameworks like Moq rely on inheritance to generate the mocks. That's why methods need to be virtual. If you want to mock static or private methods, try Microsoft Fakes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: Thanks, my question is rather framework agnostic. I would like to know what is the issue with using concrete implementation (in some cases its obvious, e.g. filesystem, DB connection etc.)

Comment: But I would say with using concrete types there is much bigger problem - I need to create an actual instance, that might have external dependencies etc. I mean, I simply cannot tell DateTime to return the same time everytime. Isnt the main reason for using interfaces?

Comment: DateTime is a tough one. I usually wrap it in an interface call.

Comment: But this will be true probably with most object that are not trivial, so I assume I see now why are interfaces important - i define the type to provide the responses I need. E.g. mocking an object User might be impossible if during the creation, his IP is being obtained and stored. So IUser and fake instance probably is the way. RIght?

Answer (score 4):

It is not must to have interface as dependency but that's recommended and widely followed practice.

Using interface and base classes as dependency helps you creating lossely couple design.
Loosely coupled design makes it possible to create modules/layers of application without depending on the implementation details about other layer.
This also makes it super easy to test the piece of code in isolation without worrying about how other layer would work or react.
This type of testing is called unit testing.

If you have dependency on concrete class then you can't unit test code in isolation. Such tests are prone to fail whenever implementation of dependency changes. If your code is dependent on actual file system class or data access class which connects to actual db then there are chances that the unit tests will fail when file is not accessible or db server is down or data is currupted.

This even won't be called unit testing. It is called integration testing.

As I mentioned, while testing code in isolation you don't need to worry about how the dependency works. That's why, while unit testing the dependencies are mocked. Also dependencies must not be an interface. It can be a base class too. When you mock dependency, mocks do not have actual implementation of any of the functionality. How many ways you can create mocks, is a different topics altogether.

Using mocks, in unit testing, you just need to make sure that they behave per your expectations while you test the code your current class. So you ask the mock to behave the way you want, make sure that certain methods or properties of mock called, so that you can cover all the paths of the piece of code which you are testing.

Following is a simple example of Unit Testing with dependency.

```
public class ProductService
{
    private IProductRepository repository;
    public ProductService (IProductRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Product GetProductById(int productId)
    {
        if(productId <= 0)
            return null;

        var product = this.repository.GetProductById(productId);

        return product;
    }
}
```

While Creating ProductService class, even if I don't have actual implementation of IProductRepository interface, I can still unit test ProductService class as following.

```
public class ProductServiceTests
{
    ProductService serviceToTest;
    IProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductServiceTests()
    {
        this.productRepository = Mock<IProductRepository>();
        this.serviceToTest = new ProductService(productRepository);
    }

    public void GetProductByIdReturnsNullIfProductIdIsZero()
    {
        int productid = 0;

        var product = serviceToTest.GetProductById(productid);
        Assert.That(product, Is.Null);
    }

    public void GetProductByIdReturnsNullIfProductIdIsNegative()
    {
        int productid = -1;
        var product = serviceToTest.GetProductById(productid);
        Assert.That(product, Is.Null);
    }

    public void GetProductByIdReturnsProductIfProductIdIsPositive()
    {
        var productid = 1;

        var product = new Product { Id = productId };

        productRepository.Setup(repo => repo.GetProductById(productid)).Returns(product); //Making sure that GetProductById method of repository is called and return an object of product as this call is part of the code which I am testing right now.

        var product = serviceToTest.GetProductById(productid);

        Assert.That(product, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(product.Id, Is.EqualTo<int>(productid));
    }
}
```

This is an example code to illustrate the unit testing. It might not build or run as expected and I apologies for that.

### edit

Found an excellent article on mocking classes https://www.wrightfully.com/how-net-mocking-frameworks-work

This should clear doubts of how class mocking is different than the interface mocking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if the expected parameter repository was not an interface but actual type Repository, could I still mock it?

Comment: Yes, you can still mock it as long as it's not a sealed class. It's not recommended and valid design practice though. It will be problem when you introduce a new repository to replace the existing one as you need to change the code so that the service knows about the new repository. It will break your unit tests too. With interface, such cases can be easily handled by changing configurations in DI Container without changing the service class.

Comment: But how? What if the object is quite complex (e.g. expects a lot of parameters in the constructor) that are references etc.

Comment: Which object is quite complex? The repository? To create mock you don't need to worry about the parameters or constructor of repository. As I said in the answer, it's mock. It does not have any implementation of any member. If you are talking about `DoIt` method, you have to create mock of every dependency which is passed as argument in it.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, I am just following the other case - let's say there is no interface type, but Repository type. So to unit test that, you have to pass actual instance of Repository, correct? But what if repository needs some other objects to be created? I know that using interface this is not an issue, just interested how to mock actual object.

Comment: Do you want to unit test Repository? or the class which is dependent on repository?

Comment: Just imagine in your code example there is no IRepository, but just repository. No interface used. How would you test that then?

Comment: You create mock of `Repository` instead of `IRepository`. `this.productRepository = Mock<Repository>();`. If you are using proper mocking framework you don't need  to pass any parameters to it's constructor. Let's discuss this further on chat if you still have any doubts. You can try RhinoMock or Moq for creating Mocks and using them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135610/discussion-between-user970696-and-chetan-ranpariya).